DSLR file sequence/order of execution for rules - Drools 6.4.0 & 7.0.0
I have a project running using drools 6.4.0 and trying to upgrade to 7.0.0
The issue I am facing is -
In Drools 6.4.0, in DSLR file I see 2 rules matching and it returns the 2nd rule in result, while
In Drools 7.0.0, it returns the first matching rule.
rule "My First Rule"
when
    Conditions for first rule
    Not routed yet
then
    Route to "First".
end

rule "My Second Rule"
when
    Conditions for second rule
    Not routed yet
then
    Route to "Second".
end

Note: I am not using salience for any of my rules.
Both rules are satisfying the conditions but here for Drools 6.4.0, it routes to "Second" while in Drools 7.0.0, it routes to "First".
I am using StatelessKieSession in 7.0.0 and StatelessKnowledgeSession in 6.4.0
Here is the code
Code for 6.4.0
public StatelessKnowledgeSession stateMapppingKnowledgeSession(MyUtil myUtil) 
{
    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    DecisionTableConfiguration config = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newDecisionTableConfiguration();
    config.setInputType(DecisionTableInputType.XLS);
    kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("META-INF/drools/rulesExcel.xls"), ResourceType.DTABLE, config);
    
    if (kbuilder.hasErrors()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to compile state mapping rules:" + kbuilder.getErrors().toString());
    }
    KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
    kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
    StatelessKnowledgeSession knowledgeSession = kbase.newStatelessKnowledgeSession();
    knowledgeSession.setGlobal("MyUtil", myUtil);
    
    return knowledgeSession;
}

Code for 7.0.0
public StatelessKieSession stateMapppingKnowledgeSession(MyUtil myUtil) 
{
    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    DecisionTableConfiguration config = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newDecisionTableConfiguration();
    config.setInputType(DecisionTableInputType.XLS);
    kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("META-INF/drools/rulesExcel.xls"), ResourceType.DTABLE, config);
    
    if (kbuilder.hasErrors()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to compile state mapping rules:" + kbuilder.getErrors().toString());
    }
    KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
    kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
    StatelessKieSession knowledgeSession = kbase.newStatelessKieSession();
    knowledgeSession.setGlobal("MyUtil", myUtil);
    
    return knowledgeSession;
}

Is there any change between version 6.4.0 to 7.0.0 in order of execution or priority or salience default value or any other behaviour?
I am trying to understand what has changed between 6.4.0 to 7.0.0?

There is no guaranteed execution order in Drools, nor has there ever been.
The only ordering guarantee is by salience -- eg. if you give a rule salience 100 and another rule salience 90, then the rule with the higher salience is guaranteed to run first.
But if you have two rules with the same salience, then there is no guaranteed order in which order they will execute. Usually it's the order they were read into memory, but even that's not guaranteed.
Rules with no declared salience have salience 0.
While it is likely that the rules will execute consistently within the same compiled version of code, even that's not guaranteed. (This actually caused some very interesting bugs that I investigated a number of years ago; when my service was restarted, one time out of ~500 the rules executed in a different order. Another time I would see inconsistent execution ordering when under extremely heavy load.)
If you want your rules to execute in a consistent order you need to either:

give your rules salience so that rule A is guaranteed to fire before rule B
make your rules more specific -- either mutually exclusive, or if they fire under the same conditions, make rule B not fire until rule A has been fired.

Without setting saliences, you can't assume any ordering at all.

In your example, you have two rules with no declared salience, so they're implicitly salience 0. Neither rule has priority.
Your rules have very simple conditions, and both key on "no route triggered", and both key on some conditions specific to that rule.
Given the "no route triggered" condition makes me think that you don't ever want both rules to fire (eg because one "my first rule" fires, a route has triggered, therefore the "no route triggered" condition is no longer valid), then your best path forward is likely to make your rules more specific if salience is not an option.
Unfortunately how to do that is beyond the scope of an appropriate Q&A because we're dealing with business decisions. eg. if rule A triggers on "color == red" and rule B triggers on "age > 10", these are not mutually exclusive, and which one of these rules should fire is a specific to your problem domain.
